# jquery check variable values

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery I have the following 4 variables.

```
var add
var city
var state
var zip
```

I need to check to see that any one of the above have a value. 
If none have a value that is OK. If all of them have a value that is OK.

Just need to check that at least one of them do not have a value.
Not sure what is the most efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have the following four variables in Javascript? :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var check = [ add, city, state, zip ].every( function ( v ) { return !!v } )
```

Just for the sake of showing off.

Explaination: the `every` method loops through all the array and returns `false` if *one* of the conditions returns `false` and stops immediately the loop. If all the loops return `true`, `true` is returned.

PS: `v` is for "variable".

Answer (score 3):

```
var check = (function(a, b, c, d) {
    return !!a && !!b && !!c && !!d;
}(add, city, state, zip));

console.log(check);
```

another method... lets learn some new techniques today!

this will actually check to see if the value is not false. anything else is ok (strings, numerics, TRUE).

Comment: Meh, that's just ugly :p although fun ^^

Comment: Btw, this will also return false if there is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!add || !city || !state || !zip) {
    console.log('exists var with no value');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to check i a variable has a value assign it to it you can do:

```
var myVar
....
if (typeof myVar === 'undefined'){
  // here goes your code if the variable doesn't have a value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
if (yourVar)
{
    // if yourVar has value  then true other wise false.
}
```

Hope thats what you required..

Answer (score 0):

```
if( add.length == 0 || zip.length == 0 || city.length == 0 || state.length == 0) {    
    alert("at least one of the variables has no value");      
};   else if (add.length == 0 & zip.length == 0 & city.length == 0 & state.length == 0) {
         alert("all of the variables are empty");
     }; else { alert("okay"); }
```